# Can we extract all Visitor ID's from Adobe Analytics using API

Tags: api, adobe-analytics, visitors

I'm looking to determine whether it's possible via visitor API to be able to find out all visitor ID's.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the code examples below, **`[your mcorgid here]`** is your company's marketing cloud organization id. If you do not know this then you need to contact Adobe Client Care to get it.

**[getMarketingCloudVisitorID](https://marketing.adobe.com/resources/help/en_US/mcvid/mcvid-getmcvid.html) - Get the Marketing Cloud Visitor ID (mid= param)**

```
var visitor = Visitor.getInstance("[your mcorgid here]@AdobeOrg")
var mcvid = visitor.getMarketingCloudVisitorID();
```

**[getAnalytcisVisitorID](https://marketing.adobe.com/resources/help/en_US/mcvid/mcvid_idvars.html) - get legacy visitor id (aid= if applicable)**

```
var visitor = Visitor.getInstance("[your mcorgid here]@AdobeOrg")
var aid = visitor.getAnalyticsVisitorID();
```

**[getCustomerIDs](https://marketing.adobe.com/resources/help/en_US/mcvid/mcvid-authenticated-state.html) - get all customer IDs**

```
var visitor = Visitor.getInstance("[your mcorgid here]@AdobeOrg");
var customerIDs = visitor.getCustomerIDs();
```

**[s_fid](https://marketing.adobe.com/resources/help/en_US/sc/implement/visid_fallback.html) - Fallback ID**

There is no built-in method for retrieving this, but you can use AA's `s.c_r()` cookie reading utility function, or any other cookie reading method you have to look for the `s_fid` cookie. *(sidenote: I do not recommend using DTM's `_satellite.readCookie()`method. It only looks for cookies on the current page's full (**not** root) domain, and there is no way to change that. Since AA and most other things usually set on root domain, it makes `_satellite.readCookie()` unreliable in practice).*

```
var fid = s.c_r('s_fid');
```

Comment: how can i get visitor id from adobe analytics using API??

Comment: @user7104273 my answer shows the methods, links to the documentation, and example code for getting the visitor id using the Visitor API.  That's what you asked for and that's what my answer shows. Perhaps you are talking about a different Adobe API, for example the [Adobe Analytics API](https://marketing.adobe.com/developer/documentation/analytics-reporting-1-4/whatsnew) ? because that is something completely different

Comment: Thanks for your solution

Answer (score 0):

Use Adobe datawarehouse and extract Experience Cloud ID. Assuming you know how to use the API already, here is an easy report to try

```
report_definition = ReportDefinition(
    dimensions="marketingcloudvisitorid",
    metrics="visits",
    date_from=insertdate,
    date_to=insertdate,
    source="warehouse"
)
```